# Does \@tocrmarg work for chapters?

Tags: table-of-contents, margins

I am working on a dissertation based on [USFDissertation](http://shell.cas.usf.edu/~saito/grad/USFDissertation.cls). I need to set at least 0.5" distance between the title text and the page number. However, when I modify the `\@tocrmarg` command, it does not take affect on chapter titles.
Here is a sample .tex file:

```
\documentclass[]{USFDissertation}
%\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@tocrmarg{15.55em} % versus 2.55em
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents   

\chapter{this is very very very very extremely incredibly long chapter title that is giving me trouble}

\section{This is a very very long section title but listens to tocrmarg and breaks when needed}

\chapter{this chapter title is shorter}

\end{document}
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Any idea how I can fix it?
Thanks :)

Comment: But `\@tocrmarg` controls the right margin, not the separation between titles and page numbers. The command controlling the distance between titles and page numbers is `\@pnumwidth` so you need either `\def\@pnumwidth{0.5in}` (in a `.cls` file or a `.sty` file) or 
` \makeatletter
\def\@pnumwidth{0.5in}
\makeatother` in a `.tex` file.

Comment: I took the liberty of cutting down your example to the minimal amount of code to show the problem. Also, similar issues show up in the report class.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Check the minimized example. You may still have the answer, but it's definitely working with `\@tocrmarg` on sections.

Comment: @MikeRenfro this minimized example produces errors: `! Undefined control sequence.
\baselinestretch ->\linespacingfactor`

Comment: Weird. Maybe old aux files? I've built this one as-is repeatedly (I think). Regardless, I'm sure you have the right solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it doesn't. The explanation is that `\@tocrmarg` (which controls the right margin indentation for all but last line of multiple-line entries) is only used in `\dottedtocline`, so only the entries for sectional unit typeset using `\@dottedtocline` (such as section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph entries in `book` and `report`) will obey changes to `\@tocrmarg`.

On the other hand, chapter (and also part) entries, at least in the standard `book` and `report` document class, are *not* typeset using `\dottedtocline` nor any parameter depending on `\@tocrmarg`, so chapter (and part) entries don't obey to changes in this latter parameter.

If you want to change the distance between titles and page numbers, you have two options; which one to choose will depend on the desired result.

1. Instead of changing `\@tocmarg`, you can redefine `\@pnumwidth` which gives the width of the box reserved to typeset page numbers. To do so, you need either `\def\@pnumwidth{0.5in}` (in a `.cls` file or a `.sty` file) or

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \def\@pnumwidth{0.5in}
   \makeatother
   ```

   in a `.tex` file. A complete example with your example code:

   ```
   \documentclass[boldheadings,thrmdefs,bbm,ams]{USFDissertation}

   \def\linespacingfactor{2}
   \def\parindentvalue{1cm}

   \usepackage[noframe]{showframe}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \usepackage{setspace,rotating,indentfirst,color,epsfig,subfigure,epstopdf,booktabs,longtable,multirow,wrapfig,url,pdflscape,caption}
   \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
   \captionsetup[table]{font={stretch=1}}
   \captionsetup[figure]{font={stretch=1}}
   \allowdisplaybreaks

   \makeatletter
   \def\@pnumwidth{0.5in}
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}

   \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\linespacingfactor} %
   \normalfont

   \tableofcontents   

   \dissertation

   \chapter[\uppercase{this is very very long chapter title that is giving me trouble}]{\uppercase{this is very very long chapter title that is giving me trouble}}
   \pagenumbering{arabic}\pagestyle{plain}
   \lipsum[1]
   \section{This is a very very long section title but listens to tocrmarg and breaks when needed}

   \chapter[\uppercase{this chapter title is shorter}]{\uppercase{this chapter title is shorter}}
   \lipsum[1]

   \end{document}
   ```

   The resulting ToC:

   [image]
2. Another option would be to keep the change to `\@tocmarg` and make chapter entries obbey `\@tocrmarg` and this can be done by redefining `\l@chapter`:

   ```
   \documentclass[boldheadings,thrmdefs,bbm,ams]{USFdissertation}

   \def\linespacingfactor{2}
   \def\parindentvalue{1cm}

   \usepackage[noframe]{showframe}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \usepackage{setspace,rotating,indentfirst,color,epsfig,subfigure,epstopdf,booktabs,longtable,multirow,wrapfig,url,pdflscape,caption}
   \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
   \captionsetup[table]{font={stretch=1}}
   \captionsetup[figure]{font={stretch=1}}
   \allowdisplaybreaks

   \makeatletter
   \renewcommand\@tocrmarg{0.5in}
   \renewcommand*\l@chapter{\@dottedtocline{0}{1.5em}{2em}}
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}

   \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\linespacingfactor} %
   \normalfont

   \tableofcontents   

   \dissertation

   \chapter[\uppercase{this is very very long chapter title that is giving me trouble}]{\uppercase{this is very very long chapter title that is giving me trouble}}
   \pagenumbering{arabic}\pagestyle{plain}
   \lipsum[1]
   \section{This is a very very long section title but listens to tocrmarg and breaks when needed}

   \chapter[\uppercase{this chapter title is shorter}]{\uppercase{this chapter title is shorter}}
   \lipsum[1]

   \end{document}
   ```

   Now the result is

   [image]

   The difference with the first option is that now all but the last line in multiple-line entries are at `0.5in` from the right margin while the last line is separated by `\@pnumwidth` from the numbers.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I have to have the leader going to the page numbers so I cannot use the first option. The second suggestion works, but then I no longer have the vertical spacing before the chapters, and when I add `\vskip 1.48em` it doesn't work.

Comment: I should have written `\renewcommand*\l@chapter{\vskip 1.48em \@plus.2\p@\@dottedtocline{0}{0em}{0.9em}}` to have the vertical spacing right.