# Need to Leave Space in Table of Contents when Entries are Multiple Lines

Tags: tables, spacing, tocloft

For my dissertation I have some title entries that span multiple lines. I am using tocloft at the moment. The problem is that my school needs me to leave an extra 0.5" of space at the end of the line when this happens and a 0.25" indent on the next line. This is also an issue for my list of figures.

This is the exact wording:
"When a heading is long, the text must stop 0.5" away from the right, 1" margin before continuing onto the next line."

Example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\textheight  9.0in
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

%Make headers 12 pt (new):
\usepackage[tiny,center]{titlesec}

%Table of contents
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage[toc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{0.5in}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{1in}

%Space between figure legend entries:
\renewcommand\cftfigafterpnum{\vskip12pt\par}


%Adds leader dots everywhere:
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftdotsep}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}

\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\footskip}{.25in}
        \begin{spacing}{1}
        \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize  Table of Contents\hfill}
        \renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
        \renewcommand\cftsecfont{\mdseries}
        \renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\mdseries}
        \tableofcontents
        \end{spacing}
    \pagebreak

\section{Very long title aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa}

hello
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Edit: The first part of my question has been answered elsewhere. But not the 0.25" indents for the second line of an entry.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show a minimal compilable example for your question.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. Any chance of making your headings only a single line in the ToC: `\caption[short ToC entry]{Main long entry}` and similarly for `\chapter` and the like.

Comment: \section etc. has an optional [short title] which is used for the toc and the headers.

Comment: Instead of asking multiple questions per question, stick to the one you've found the answer for. Now edit the question to just pose the one question that's answered. Then write a new question as a follow-up question. See [I've just been told I have to post a follow-up question, why and how?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the first part of my question is answered here:
[Does \@tocrmarg work for chapters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251455/does-tocrmarg-work-for-chapters)
with:
`\makeatletter \renewcommand \@tocrmarg{0.5in} \makeatother`

Answer (score 0):

I avoid packages like tocloft as they simply complicate matters.  Instead I modify `\l@section` etc. directly.

If I understand your requirements, all you need is `\leftskip=0.25in` and `\rightskip=0.5in` (as opposed to `\@tempdima` and `\pnumwidth`), which is a much simpler change than a single line test and `\hangindent`.

For the list of figures, just repeat the process with `\l@figure`.

OTOH, this is a simple enough change that tocloft should be able to handle it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\textheight  9.0in
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in, showframe]{geometry}

%Make headers 12 pt (new):
\usepackage[tiny,center]{titlesec}

%Table of contents
\usepackage[toc,title]{appendix}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}

\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}% width for \numberline
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip 0.5in
      \parfillskip -0.5in
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip by 0.25in
      \hskip -\leftskip
      {#1}\nobreak
      \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2\kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\clearpage
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\footskip}{.25in}
        \begin{spacing}{1}
        \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize  Table of Contents\hfill}
        \tableofcontents
        \end{spacing}
    \pagebreak

\section{A normal section}

hello

\section{\blindtext}

hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I might try this eventually, unfortunately I'll need to also add the other requirements such as leader dots.